# Check existence of distinct values for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization, distinct

EDITED:

Suppose I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`pv_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`time_stamp` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`value` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
PRIMARY KEY (`pv_name`, `time_stamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I can find each `pv_name` that has more than one distinct `value` in this table using the following query:

```
SELECT events.pv_name
FROM events
GROUP BY events.pv_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT events.value) > 1;
```

The issue is that this query is not efficient. It counts all of the distinct values instead of stopping after finding more than one.

One suggestion has been the following:

```
SELECT events.pv_name
FROM events
GROUP BY events.pv_name
HAVING MIN(events.value) < MAX(events.value);
```

This is efficient if the index includes `value`. However, `value` is a text column so it can not.

Is there another approach that would make this search more efficient? Some form of correlated subquery perhaps? I would like to stay with MySQL, but if there is a feature in another database server that would help this I might consider moving to it.

Comment: how often are inserts occuring? What are the timeliness accuracy requirements?

Comment: I don't have a good fixed number for the rate of inserts. It can be as fast as the database permits. I'm not sure what you mean by timeliness accuracy?

Comment: Can there be a lag in the amount that stats are accurate. This type of info rules out, or makes possible, different strategies

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Customers
GROUP BY pv_name 
HAVING MIN(time_stamp ) < MAX(time_stamp )` ;

You have `time_stamp` for value

Comment: @Drew: There is no problem assuming the table is frozen at the time of the query if that is what you mean? That is you can ignore any rows that might be added during the execution of the query.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode: That is close to what I had before, but it appears to take too long if `value` can not be part of the index.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it is probably best to avoid `group by` or `distinct`.  First, though, I would suggest adding an auto-incremented `event_id` for the table.  This makes it possible to determine whether or not two rows are the same.

So, I would suggest the following query:

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.time_stamp between $ts1 and $ts2 and
      exists (select 1
              from events e2
              where e2.pv_name = e.pv_name and
                    e2.time_stamp between $ts1 and $ts2 and
                    e2.event_id < e.event_id
             );
```

You also want indexes:  `events(time_stamp, pv_name, event_id)` and `events(pv_name, time_stamp, event_id)`.

This finds pairs of events.  You can use `select distinct pv_name`.  However, that incurs a bunch of extra processing to remove the duplicates.

Comment: This does not seem to compare the values?

Comment: Compare what values?  You question is about getting lists of names.

Comment: The names that have more than one distinct value in the given time interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE pv_name IN
(SELECT pv_name FROM Customers GROUP BY pv_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AND
 time_stamp BETWEEN 'start_time' and `end_time'
```

OR

`SELECT *
FROM Customers
GROUP BY pv_name 
HAVING MIN(time_stamp ) < MAX(time_stamp )` ;

This may work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following may work? Can it be improved upon?

```
-- Chooses a single non null `value` from the `events` table for each `pv_name`.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE single_values ( PRIMARY KEY (pv_name) ) ENGINE=Memory AS (
SELECT events.pv_name, events.value
FROM events
WHERE events.value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY events.pv_name );

-- Finds each `pv_name` that has a `value` different than the one for it in `single_values`.
-- This is a correlated subquery.
SELECT single_values.pv_name
FROM single_values
WHERE 1 = (
SELECT 1
FROM events
WHERE events.pv_name = single_values.pv_name
AND events.value <> single_values.value
AND events.value IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1 );
```