# Caching the data result of complex computation

Tags: mysql, spring, caching, memcached

I have a Spring Boot server application. Clients of this server ask for statistics about different things all the time. These statistics can be shared among clients, and must not be real time.

It's good enough if these statistics are refreshed every 15-30 mins.

Also, computing these statistics requires reading the whole database.

So, I'd like to cache these computed statistics and update them now and then.

What is your suggestion, what tool or pattern should I use?

I have the following ideas so far:

- [using memcached](http://memcached.org/)
- upgrading to MySQL 5.7 which has JSON store, and store the data there

Please keep in mind that the hardware of my server is not too powerful: 512MB RAM and 1 CPU (cheapest option in DigitalOcean).

Thank you in advance!

Edit 1:

These statistics are composed of quite simple data structures: int to int maps, lists, etc. and they are NOT fitting well for a relational database.

Edit 2:

The whole data is only a few megabytes. The crutial point is that creating this data requires a lot of database reads, and a lot of clients are asking for it.
I also want to keep my server application stateless. I think it's important to mention.

Comment: what if you were to house statistics as you go (as data changes, as *stuff* happens). Key Metrics, not everything.

Comment: @Drew That's also an option, but how should I store it, and where?

Comment: we don't even know what the it is. Share whatever you want, or change the content as a strawman we can beat on. I would be happy to offer some suggestions

Comment: I edited the question. Does it help?

Comment: in the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33226821) the gent showed a table, and talked about his `pv_name` and `value` columns. What I would have done was answered that with a metrics table for pv_names (albeit large). His metrics could be available at anytime without calculating them. He had rather constraining issues. All questions are different. Most OPs just drop the ball and never continue on with giving good feedback. So we vanish on to the next question, or watch Netflix

Comment: I'm not going to show a database table, or anything like that, because it's irrelevant. The server makes calculations based on all the tables, and the result is some data. This data should be cached until the next calculation is finished. The question is: what is the best practice to store such data? I think it is quite straigthforward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92901/discussion-between-lordscone-and-drew).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for the problem, is saving the data in JSON format to a file, and that's it.
Additionally, this file can be on a ram disk partition, so it will be blazing fast.